# electron-builder refuses to work with 256 by 256 icon

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

Im trying to build a electron app using electron builder and I am getting the following error: `Error: image /home/runner/work/granio/granio/build/icon.ico must be at least 256x256`. This error is suprising because I tripled checked that the icon is in fact, 256x256. Is this a bug with electron? [Icon Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxKff.png)

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with docker.
Because I put my electron project in a directory not isolated.
I used an Apache's HTTP server (https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) and I put the project in the directory `usr/local/apache/` with others files.
I suspect that to build an electron project you must have a directory with only project's files. Otherwise, electron-builder throws that error.

I hope this help someone!